# preg_match if first char is slash

Tags: php, preg-match

I try to find out if the first char of a string is a slash.

I have this string `/var/www/html`

```
$mystring = "/var/www/html";
$test = preg_match("/^/[.]/", $mystring);

if ($test == 1)
{
    echo "ret = 1";
}
else 
{
    echo "ret = 0";
}
```

But I always get `ret = 0`.

Comment: A non-regex solution is probably easier, but the reason yours doesn't work, is that you need to escape the forward slash as you use it as the delimiter.

Comment: I see, thank you. And i also have to remove the brackets `[ ]` to make it work. `/^\/./`

Comment: True, your original regex searches for a forward slash followed by a dot...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$mystring = "/var/www/html";
$test = preg_match("/^\//", $mystring);

if ($test == 1)
{
    echo "ret = 1";
}
else 
{
    echo "ret = 0";
}
```

Comment: Almost right. But when you want to fetch the first char it's actually `"/^\//"`

Comment: Why is there a backslash before the forward slash? Do i have to mask the slash by placing a backslash before it?

Comment: There's a backslash before because slashes are reserved characters or delimeters for expressions. Backslashes are needed before a delimeter

Comment: Slash means start of regex generally. So if you want to use slash as slash you need to escape the regex to make slash slash. Same thing with dot, a dot means any char, but backslash-dot means dot

Comment: @RenCamp The forward slash is not special, the reason it needs escaping here is because it is used as the delimiter. If you used another delimiter, you would not need to escape it.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `strpos()` for that:

```
<?php
    $mystring = "/var/www/html";
    if(strpos($mystring,"/") === 0){
        echo "ret = 1";
    }else{
        echo "ret = 0";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm wrong here, but won't strpos search the full sting for / and not just first char?

Comment: yes, but it seach for the position of given string, in your case `/` which position is 0 - It gives you the position of the first occurrence.

Comment: Aaa! True. I didn't think of ===0. I usually use strpos with === false. Didn't think of the "actual" use of the function :-)

Answer (score 3):

Any reason why you have to use preg_match?

Can't you use substr?

```
if (substr($mystring, 0, 1) == "/") {
  echo "ret= 1";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is all you want to do then you can also do something like this :

```
echo $mystring[0] == "/" ? "ret 1" : "ret 0";
```

No need to use other functions really.

Answer (score -3):

You have to escape the **/** in your  pattern, as you are already using it as your regex delimeter, so try this :

```
$mystring = "/var/www/html";
$test = preg_match("/^\//", $mystring);

if ($test == 1)
{
    echo "ret = 1";
}
else 
{
    echo "ret = 0";
}
```

Comment: @OleK I swear of God, I did not steal your comments and answers of other posters :D